# How to make unordered list elements wrap around into another column

Tags: html, css

I have an ordered list inside a div. The li elements overflow through the bottom of the div; however, I want them to wrap into another column on the right.

Hopefully this explains what I have versus what I want:

[image]

My HTML and CSS looks like:

```
.some-div
{
    background-color: #FEEBCC;
    padding: 5px;    
}


.some-div p
{
    width: 35%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}


.some-div ul
{
    list-style: disc;
    color: #5C2946;
    width: 60%;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 50px;
}


 <div class="some-div">
        <h3>Learn How to Fund It</h3>
        <p>You can use the following assets to fund a charitable gift annuity:</p>
            <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a class="flyover-link" rel="#cashcga-flyover">Cash</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="flyover-link" rel="#appreciatedsecuritiescga-flyover">Appreciated Securities</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="flyover-link" rel="#closelyheldstockcga-flyover">Closely Held Stock</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="flyover-link" rel="#realestatecga-flyover">Real Estate</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="flyover-link" rel="#tangiblepersonalpropertycga-flyover">Tangible Personal Property </a>
                    </li>
            </ul>        
    </div>
```

I can't change that tag structure because I'm using a Content Management System.

**BONUS POINT:** Why isn't the background color getting applied to the entire div????

Answer (score 0):

This is because some `html elements` did have their default `values` so you need to make them `0`. So i suggest you to just add the following css hack to your code which voids the default values of html element.

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
}
```

NOTE : You `ul` is already wrapped in your `div`.

**[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vhs4vpz8/)**

Answer (score 0):

The li elements are hard coded into your list. To put them into a div you can either hard code them into the preferred div or use javascript to dynamically change the html code. It would probably be easier to just code a short list into the adjacent div, but if this is a list that gets generated in some way, css can change how things are displayed, but the location of you li items are still part of the parent div. Css is for styling and placing on the screen not for changing parent elements.